# meaning of "out of the season" in this sentence

Tags: vocabulary, phrase-meaning

It's something said by a production manager: "I'm responsible for the refining process, and I organise the shift system...Out of the season, I supervise the overhaul of the plant." Does "out of the season" mean "holiday season"? (But I wonder why she has to work if it's holiday season. Does it mean holiday season for people in general?)

Comment: Difficult to say without more context. Do they mean 'out of the (refining) season ? Do they overhaul the plant when there is no refining to do ? What are they refining ? Something seasonal ? (I'm getting worked up about this. I need a cup of tea.)

Comment: They are refining sugar. I think it may mean "out of the refining season". The whole text is as follows: I'm responsible for the refining process, and I organise the shift system. We have a continuous process, and it's my job to see that materials flow smoothly and at the right rate...and that what comes out at the end is sugar and not something else! Out of the season, I supervise the overhaul of the plant."

Comment: Btw, does the "shift system" here mean people's work schedule? I wonder if she may refer to something related to a machine.

Comment: Yes. A shift is one period of work. It refers to work done outside of the usual daily 9-5 business hours working time. Evening shifts and night shifts are common. 'Double day shifts' refer to early and late shifts (0600 to 1400 and 1400 to 2200, perhaps).

Comment: 'Out of the season' means out of some kind of a season that has been made clear by the context. If the context in this case does not make clear what the season is, that is a problem with this particular text, not a feature of English language and usage.

Answer (score 3):

[Sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar) comes from plants (refined sugar often comes from sugarcane and sugar beets), and most plants only grow in certain seasons of the year. So "out of the season" means outside the time of the year when the factory is busy refining the sugar from the plants that have been harvested. At those times she's busy supervising the overhaul of the factory for the next year.